# performance of OpenDns versus Google Dns?

Tags: dns, opendns, google-dns

A bunch of articles were written on this topic in 2009...wondering if there's a more updated comparison of the performance between the two?

Comment: Google DNS does not fool you with nonexistend or local domain names, where OpenDNS at least did maybe stil does. Google is even faster than the DNS of my provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Namebench](http://code.google.com/p/namebench/) can help you test for yourself which DNS is faster in your location or the [DNS Benchmark](https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm)